# Error in calling module from subfolder with module calling another module within the same folder

Tags: python

I have current set up as below

```
/MainProject
  __init__.py
  main.py
    /Functions
      initiation.py
      weekly_rank.py
      __init__.py
```

main.py is doing:

```
from Functions import weekly_rank
weekly_rank.function()
```

and weekly_rank.py is importing initiation.py to get some variables to use in weekly_rank.py

and when I try running main.py, I get a error message saying

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'initiation'
```

I tried doing:

```
from Functions import initiation
```

in main.py but still didn't work.

Comment: @MarioKhoury sorry! Functions is the name of the folder, edited in the post!

Comment: In order to import from a folder name Functions you gotta use import Functions.initiation or from Functions.initiation import whatever_thing_you_wanna_import. Basically, you can't import a directory, you import a file **inside** a directory

Answer (score 1):

Can you try doing it like that:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, './Functions/')
import initiation

//Here you can now use initiation.function()
```

I don't think it is the best approach but it is a work arround